# How to prove $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ using induction?

Tags: summation, induction

This is as far as I get.  I get stuck here because both sides to not equal each other, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

$$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$

Assume: $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{c}\frac{k}{(k+1)!} = 1 – 1/(c+1)!$

Prove: $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{c+1}\frac{k}{(k+1)!} = 1 – 1/((c+1)+1)!$

$$\sum_{k=1}^c \frac{k}{(k+1)!} + \frac{c+1}{((c+1)+1)!} \stackrel{?}{=}  1- \frac{1}{((c+1)+1)!}$$

$$1 – \frac{1}{(c+1)!} + \frac{(c+1)}{((c+1)+1)!} \stackrel{?}{=} 1 – \frac{1}{((c+1)+1)!}$$

Comment: I provide a simple way of handling this one, but please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a common denominator on your left hand side (noting that $(c+1)+1 = c+2$ and that $(c+2)! = (c+2)(c+1)!$):

\begin{eqnarray}
1 - \frac{1}{(c+1)!} + \frac{c+1}{(c+2)!} &=& 1 - \frac{c+2}{(c+1)!(c+2)} + \frac{c+1}{(c+2)!} \\ 
&=&  1 - \frac{c+2}{(c+2)!} + \frac{c+1}{(c+2)!}
\end{eqnarray}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sorry, I am still not fully understanding.  On the first line, I see how you got the left hand side, but I am not sure how you derived the right hand side.

Comment: The right hand side was just obtained from the left hand side by multiplying the middle term by $\frac{c+2}{c+2}$. I made a common denominator with the last two terms.

Comment: Where did you get c+2 from?

Comment: @OmarN The $c+2$ comes from the fact that in the middle term you have $(c+1)!$ but in the third term you have $(c+2)!$. We know that $(c+2)! = (c+2)(c+1)!$ so to make a common denominator for the last two terms, you need to get $(c+2)(c+1)!$ in the denominator for the middle term. To make that happen, you need to multiply the middle term by $\frac{c+2}{c+2}$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Gotcha!  Makes sense now.  I think my issue is I was not sure how to represent the product of (c+1)! and (c+2).  I see now that if you multiply those two together, you get (c+2)!.

Comment: @OmarN Glad you got it. :)

Comment: Gotcha, just accepted the answer.  Thanks again for your help Cameron.  I'm new to induction, and have been working on this literally all day.  Thanks!  And thanks to everybody else who helped.  Everyone who posted helped me out big time.  MANY thanks!

Comment: @OmarN We love to help :) Feel free to ask questions in the future if you get stuck again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the key part of the induction step:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{c+1}\frac{i}{(i+1)!} &= \frac{c+1}{(c+2)!}+\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^c\frac{i}{(i+1)!}}\tag{by defn. of $\Sigma$}\\[1em]
&= \frac{c+1}{(c+2)!}+\color{blue}{\left[1-\frac{1}{(c+1)!}\right]}\tag{by ind. hyp.}\\[1em]
&= 1+\frac{c+1}{(c+2)!}-\frac{(c+2)}{(c+2)!}\tag{manipulate}\\[1em]
&= 1-\frac{1}{(c+2)!}
\end{align}
The induction assumption is used in what is highlighted in blue, and the "key" is to realize that
$$
\frac{1}{(c+1)!}=\frac{c+2}{c+2}\cdot\frac{1}{(c+1)!}=\frac{(c+2)}{(c+2)!}.
$$

Comment: I am following most of that, but am still not clear on that third line, how are you getting common denominators?

Comment: @OmarN $(c+2)!$ is your common denominator and $c+1-(c+2)=-1$. This is what Cameron was referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the series can be evaluated without relying on proving, by induction, equality with a given expression.

Simply note that

$$\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}$$

The ensuing sum is a "telescoping sum," which is easy to evaluate as $1-1/(n+1)!$.

If we want to use induction, we may still use the "telescoping form" and write

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}\right)+1/n!-1/(n+1)!$$

The sum on the right side is, by induction hypothesis, $1-1/n!$, whereupon adding to the second term yields $1-1/(n+1)!$ thus completing the induction proof!

Answer (score 0):

In your last line, on the left side, multiply the middle fraction by $\frac{(c+1)+1}{(c+1)+1}$. This gives it the same denominator as your last fraction on that left side. Add the terms together, and voila.

Comment: where did you get that fraction from?

Comment: Its denominator is exactly what is needed to make the middle fraction have the same denominator as the fraction that follows. The numerator is just so that we are multiplying by $1$. It is pretty important to understand how factorials work for this. You need to see that these two fractions have basically the same denominator, with the middle one having an additional factor of the next integer, $(c+1)+1$.